# drop all numbers after the first five starting on the left; zip code

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have zip code information and several observations have more than five digits.  I want to keep the first five digits starting from the left. I want to edit the current table I am using, MyTable.

ZIP

29405

23471

2745000000

4738497823

I want it to look like this  (keep first five digits starting from the left)

ZIP

29405

23471

27450

47389

Answer (score 3):

One way by using the left function

```
update mytable
set zip = left(zip,5)
```

you could also use substring, look up both functions in Books On Line to see their usage

Comment: Ah, you were just a hair quicker. :-) +1.